# How do I add a PayPal button for donations for a non profit Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, paypal

I can’t find how or where I can add a *donate* button for PayPal to our page. I have seen other humane societies have this PayPal button or page and would like to add one to ours. We already have a PayPal account and I have a code generated for it, just not sure how or where to put it to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has a [donations app](https://www.facebook.com/donateapp).

There is another way to add donations if you specifically want it going to Paypal. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJr7exvnyxA) has an example for an animal shelter.